# MaxListenersExceededWarning in sails js

Tags: node.js, socket.io, sails.js, eventemitter

I am using sails js but encountered with this error

> **MaxListenersExceededWarning:** Possible EventEmitter memory leak
>   detected. 11 connection listeners added. Use **emitter.setMaxListeners()**
>   to increase limit

is it a socket issue or something else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default nodejs is set to allow 10 listeners at any event. If you want to change it you can use

```
setMaxListeners(n) //n be the number of listeners
```

Plus you can use *node --trace-warning app.js* to exactly get to the point which is generating this exception